# Acceder a items dentro del then de un promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo esta promesa que se encarga de asignarle una imagen a los items que traigo de otro endpoint, funcionaba bien hasta que quise pasarle un parametro title a la funcion getImage, tuve que poner el for fuera de esta para iterar y que le pase por cada item pero el tema es que luego no puedo asignar img a items porque items no entra dentro del then. Supongo que se deberia hacer una cadena de promises o algo asi, algun consejo?

```js
  getImage (title) {
    var headers = {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        "Api-Key": "xxx",
        "cache-control": "no-cache"
      }
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch(`https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?query=${title}&order_by=popular&client_id=xxx`, headers)
    .then(result => result.json())
    .then(data => {
      var i = getRandomInt(0, data.results.length);
      resolve(data.results[i].urls.small);
    });
  });
}

  getCards (user) {
    var _this =  this;
    fetch(backend+`/getCards/${user.id}`)
    .then(result => result.json())
    .then(items => {
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      this.getImage(items[i].title).then(function(result) {         //aca items es undefined
          items[i].img = result;
        });
      }
      _this.setState({items});
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando se resuelve la promesa, la variable `i` ya terminó de iterar y tiene el valor `items.length`, por lo que tratas de asignarle la propiedad `img` a un elemento que no existe en el array de items.

Una solución sería transformar `getCards` en una función asíncrona:

```
async getCards(user) {
    var _this = this,
        items = await fetch(backend + `/getCards/${user.id}`)
        .then(result => result.json());

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        items[i].img = await _this.getImage(items[i].title);
    }
    _this.setState({
        items
    });
}
```

Otra opción menos elegante es generar un array vacío `items_with_img` y un array de promesas, dentro de las cuales se trae la imagen y se asigna al elemento:

```
var items_wth_img=[],
    promise_array = items.map(function(item) {
       return _this.getImage(item.title).then(function(result) {
          item.img = result;
          items_with_img.push(item);
          return item;
       });
    });
return Promise.all(promise_array).then(function() {
   return _this.setState({items_with_img});
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvio lo de la funcion asyncronica

Comment: Modificando en el bucle for **var** por **let** debe mantener el valor de **i** dentro de la promesa. Si quieres acceder a items antes de que este todo resuelto, tiene que esperar a las promesas. Como bien apunta @amenadiel

Answer (score 3):

El problema que comentas está aquí entiendo, que dices que items[i].img no lo tienes disponible dentro de ese then de la promesa. Eso es así porque estás pasando la función anónima function(result)... y no tienes el this adecuado dentro.

```
this.getImage(items[i].title).then(function(result) {         //aca items es undefined
          items[i].img = result;
        });
      }
```

Prueba o usar la función flecha...

```
 this.getImage(items[i].title).then((result) => items[i].img = result);
```

O hacer un bind(this) a tu función anónima.

---

Este ejemplo sigue tus mismos principios. Como vemos el valor de **i** es incorrecto. Obtenemos una salida erronea de INDEX.

```js
function arrayAsync() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 5000);
  })
}

function getArray () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      arrayAsync().then(() => {
        resolve([1,2,3,4,5]);
      });
  });
}

function increaseAsync(value) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(++value), 1000);
  });
}

function getInfo() {
  var _this =  this;
  
  getArray()
  .then(items => {
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      this.increaseAsync(items[i]).then(function(result) {         //aca items es undefined
        console.log("index " + i + "value " + result);
      });
    }
  });
}

getInfo();
```

Con solo hacer el cambio de **var i**  a **let i** hacemos que todo funcione correctamente. Por lo tanto no hay necesidad de usar AWAIT y convertir tus llamadas en sincronas.

```js
function arrayAsync() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 5000);
  })
}

function getArray () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      arrayAsync().then(() => {
        resolve([1,2,3,4,5]);
      });
  });
}

function increaseAsync(value) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(++value), 1000);
  });
}

function getInfo() {
  var _this =  this;
  
  getArray()
  .then(items => {
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      this.increaseAsync(items[i]).then(function(result) {         //aca items es undefined
        console.log("index " + i + "value " + result);
      });
    }
  });
}

getInfo();
```